# Object not found 404 for file upload and later can't view for unicode characters

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a pdf file and later view that uploaded file, problem is it is uploading correctly but if there are some file name with unicode characters then also it is uploading, but i can't view due to URL problem getting 404 error unicode file names are encoded wrongly in my server here is the code.

```
$maxsize = 10485760;
$format = array('application/pdf');
if ($_FILES['file']['size'] >= $maxsize) {
$error_1 = 'File Size too large upload files less than 10MB';
echo '<script>alert("'.$error_1.
'")</script>'; ?
>
<
script >
    window.location = "add_files_dev.php"; </script>
<?php
}
elseif($_FILES['file']['size']==0){
    $error_2='Invalid File';
    echo '<script>alert("'.$error_2.'")</script>';
}
elseif(!in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$format)){
    $error_3='Format Not Supported.Only .PDF files are accepted';
    echo '<script>alert("'.$error_3.'")</script>';
    ?> <
script >
    window.location = "add_files_dev.php"; </script> << ?
php
} else {

$file = rand(1000, 100000).
"-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$folder = "uploads/";

// new file size in KB
$new_size = $file_size / 1024;
// new file size in KB

// make file name in lower case
$new_file_name = strtolower($file);
// make file name in lower case

$final_file = str_replace(' ', '-', $new_file_name);

}
move_uploaded_file($file_loc, $folder.$final_file)
```

Comment: Try to use `mb_strtolower($file, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: tried but still no luck again getting 404

Comment: Can you please provide some example of wrongly encodage and original file name you have.

Comment: original file name : ನಡಾವಳಿ.pdf
Wrongly encoded name : 31684-à²¨à²¡à²¾à²µà²³à²¿.pdf

I have already set the memory, post size to max length some how Unicode characters its not accepting

Comment: why it is wrongly encoded by this name any idea ??
original file name : ನಡಾವಳಿ.pdf Wrongly encoded name : 31684-à²¨à²¡à²¾à²µà²³à²¿.pdf

How to stop this if this encodes correctly then i will not have any problem in viewing the pdf files

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `AddDefaultCharset` or change if already exist in httpd.conf

`AddDefaultCharset utf-8`

if you don't have access to it create .htaccess file and put this code in

`AddDefaultCharset utf-8`

Comment: i added AddDefaultCharset utf-8 in httpd.conf and restarted my server but still i am not able to browse that file, i tried with setting mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); to default but don't know where i am making mistake file names are not converted properly after moving.

Comment: I named a file with same name you provide and run code to upload it and it works well. so the problem is in your server encodage

Comment: i think even i don't have a problem with upload as well but i can't view might be the URL problem, am i missing something here.

Is this is doing any culprit here
`$final_file = str_replace(' ', '-', $new_file_name);`